# "If a son strike his father" - shouldn't it be "strikes"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, conditionals

I am reading *The Code of Hammurabi* translated by Robert Francis Harper. Many times there are sentences in the format "if one do this, some action shall be done". Here's an example:

> If a son strike his father, they shall cut off his fingers.

I thought instead of "strike", there should be "strikes" because the 3rd person singular form with an "-s" should be used with "a son".

This lack of an 3rd person singular "-s" persists through the entire book. Is this some sort of a style, or just an honest representation of the grammar of the original language in which *The Code* was written (which I have no idea)?

Comment: This is the [subjunctive](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjunctive-mood) mood, which is no longer required in English. This particular use of it was archaic even when *The Code of Hammurabi* was translated in 1904, but would certainly have been used by Shakespeare. I have no idea whether the author used it to show where there was a subjunctive use in the original, or to give the translation a feeling of antiquity.

Comment: @PeterShor I would agree that the subjunctive is not essential, but I hear it used, if not daily, then regularly. *If I were you I would...*

Comment: @WS2 *If I were you* is the 'past subjunctive', which is indeed still common. *If a son strike* is the 'present subjunctive', which has virtually disappeared except in mandatives.

Comment: You can read is as "If a son *should* strike his father...", or perhaps "If a son *were to* strike his father...".  It's archaic.

Comment: The given context does not use the *If* in the sense where one would use the "*s* -ed" verb. Rather, I guess we are to read the *if* as a *should,* with the plain verb.

Comment: *"Should a son strike his father"* and *"if a son should strike his father"* are still the subjunctive. (At least I think they were 300 years ago; I don't know whether modern grammarians still analyze them as such.)

Comment: @StoneyB I'm not entirely clear about what *mandatives* are, but if I say *If John not be the first to know, all hell could break loose.*, that sounds subjunctive enough to my untutored ear.

Comment: @WS2 A *mandative* is a command, demand, desire: *We order that the defendant **be** discharged.* I don't think I've ever encountered a  'present subjunctive' (=uninflected plain form) employed as a conditional in ordinary contemporary speech, only in literary contexts and quotations: "If this be treason, make the most of it."

Comment: @PeterShor *Subjunctive* means different things to different analysts. Is it a property of the verb or of the clause? I think few modern grammarians would support the notion of distinct subjunctive forms such as are found in German or French, but some recognize subjunctive contexts which 'select' a distinct repertoire of verbforms and  constructions. It's basically the same problem we encounter when we try to count English 'tenses'.

Comment: @StoneyB *If Charlie be the one on guard duty, they are unlikely to escape!*

Comment: @WS2 Oh, yah, it's perfectly grammatical; but do you really hear it in everyday speech?

Comment: I wonder how many questions like this there are in this forum...  "Is this wrong?" ... "No, it is correct, it is subjunctive."

Comment: @StoneyB It certainly isn't extinct.

Comment: Though this be madness, yet there is method in't.

Comment: @SvenYargs or *...yet there be method in't*  a double subjunctive!

Comment: Common usage of present subjunctive: "If need be, …"

Answer (score 1):

No, it's correct. It's just old.

As @PeterShor and others comment, this is an example of the [subjunctive](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/subjunctive-mood) mood, which expresses hypothetical situations and which is no longer commonly used in English. Other, more exlicit, forms of your example include:

> If a son should strike his father...

---

> Should a son strike his father...

---

> If a son were to strike his father...